git, merge changes from another (related) repo (says already up to date)
This is clearly one of those "I've missed the basic principle" type issues. Luckily since everything is now "on the web" I can be very specific and not need to say "for example" (but it's the principle I want to understand).
[FYI: This got moved from "stackoverflow" because it's not about programming ... strictly true I guess ... but mostly for programmers ]
[AFYI: It seems some folks go around searching keyword matches on questions , then posting links to any that match ... so I've already found many links were people did a merge from another repo ... and it worked ...if that was the answer I'd not have posted this question]
I developing some code to drive an e-ink display. The code is at:
https://github.com/waveshareteam/e-Paper
I came across a bug and went to open an "issue" , while there I spotted there were quite a lot of "issues" and a lot of waiting "pull requests". Reading though these I realised I'd quite like some (one for now) in my version.
The one I wanted was : https://github.com/rohoog/e-Paper
(lots of fixes to avoid busy waits)
...Now I didn't do this is the methodical fashion implied here but:
git clone             https://github.com/waveshareteam/e-Paper
git remote add rohoog https://github.com/rohoog/e-Paper
git fetch  rohoog  --tags

I then did:
$ git branch -r
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
Press RETURN to continue 

  origin/Development
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
  rohoog/develop
  rohoog/master
  rohoog/rohoog/array_overflow
  rohoog/rohoog/bmp-reading
  rohoog/rohoog/compile-opt
  rohoog/rohoog/no-commit-binaries
  rohoog/rohoog/wait_pin

$ git checkout rohoog/master
$ find RaspberryPi_JetsonNano > /tmp/rohoog-master-RaspberryPi_JetsonNano
$ git checkout master
$ find RaspberryPi_JetsonNano > /tmp/origin-master-RaspberryPi_JetsonNano
$ diff /tmp/origin-master-RaspberryPi_JetsonNano  /tmp/rohoog-master-RaspberryPi_JetsonNano

The diff returned many differences. So next, I did:
$ git diff origin/master rohoog/master  > /tmp/diffs

$ wc /tmp/diffs
  561055  1374852 25309866 /tmp/diffs

(so maybe , I'll regret trying to do this ...but let's see ..I only care about a few files)
$ git branch
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
Press RETURN to continue 

* master

$ git merge rohoog/master
Already up to date.

OK...what? How?  I can see many people have had similar "blind spots" but it feels like I've followed the guidelines. What am I doing wrong?
Well there are many thousands of lines different, I'd expect something to get changed?
OK, taking comments from @Terdon:
I think the mistake I made was:

Whereas I had thought the situation I was in was :

So there were no new patches to add.. However when I did the "diff(1)" what I was seeing there the 99+ patches (deltas) that had happened in the original repo.
As you can see what I was expecting to pick up were patches P1-P7 (made up numbers here) because I thought the rohoog fork had rolled up all the changes into his master. I fact they are all separate, so since I want the "wait-pin" work I need patches P3-P5 , so I should merge from the tip of "wait-pin" branch.
Have I got this about right?
Any suggestions as to a simple check I should have done to ensure I spotted the "problem" (my misperception) .
(e.g. I was mostly guessing , working back from github pull request to the [wrong] git branch)

Did you look at the differences? Could they just be path differences, for example?

The fact that the branches are different is no indication of whether or not merging would introduce new differences. What you describe seems perfectly normal, it is just that the rohoog/master branch which you are trying to merge into master doesn't contain any new code. Perhaps it has already been merged.
For instance, consider this toy example:
$ git init
(master) $ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world!"

(master) $ git add foo.sh
(master) $ git commit -m "first commit" foo.sh
[master (root-commit) 192b827] first commit
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100755 foo.sh

(newBranch) $ git checkout -b newBranch
Switched to a new branch 'newBranch'
(newBranch) $ sed  's/Hello/Goodbye/' foo.sh > bar.sh 
(newBranch) $ ls
bar.sh  foo.sh

(newBranch) $ cat bar.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Goodbye world!"

(newBranch) $ git add bar.sh 
(newBranch) $ git commit -m "goodbye" bar.sh 
[newBranch 87746c9] goodbye
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 bar.sh

At this point, my newBranch has an extra file, so your find/diff approach would see a difference. However, if I try to merge master into it, I will see no changes:
$ git merge master
Already up to date.

As you can see, there is a situation where although find/diff will find differences, no changes will be made when merging. And, indeed, even on the github page you linked to, you can see that the rohood/master branch is 90 commits behind waveshareteam/e-Paper:master, the repo and branch is was forked off of:


OK, now I've been reading a reading this and going to github for several hours now (it's now 04:30 (so AM)  ....the change ( pull request) i was interested in (there may be more)

Not sure how I'm meant to respond now. My above comment was much longer and added more information (and was within limits) but appears truncated to the 1st line  (and it would be good if I could add a picture)

@GraemeV please add any relevant information to the question itself, not in comments. Just edit it into the question as though it had been there from the beginning. Also, just FYI, I checked with the Stack Overflow mods and this would have been perfectly on topic there too.

updated with diagrams, if I've now got this right, I can close this

I guess so, I don't know I didn't look into the actual specific changes, @GraemeV. All I know is that the branch was behind master, so you are merging an old branch into a new one. The differences, therefore, are things present in the new that are missing from the old, but merging the old into the new won't bring anything that wasn't already there.
